# Kotlin, generics, and a function that may have no arguments

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to genericise the boilerplate around a very common pattern, and Kotlin brings me tantalisingly close.

I've built a class that serves as a listener manager, as follows:

```
class GenericListenerSupport <EventArgumentType, ListenerFunction: (EventArgumentType) -> Unit> {
    private val listeners = mutableListOf<ListenerFunction>()

    fun addListener(listener: ListenerFunction) {
        listeners.add(listener)
    }

    fun removeListener(listener: ListenerFunction) {
        listeners.remove(listener)
    }

    fun fireListeners(argument: EventArgumentType) {
        listeners.forEach { it.invoke(argument) }
    }
}
```

and it can be used as follows:

```
class ExampleWithArgument {
    private val listenerSupport = GenericListenerSupport<String, (String)->Unit>()

    fun exampleAdd() {
        listenerSupport.addListener({ value -> System.out.println("My string: "+value)})
    }

    fun exampleFire() {
        listenerSupport.fireListeners("Hello")
    }
}
```

So far, so good. But what if the listener has no arguments? Or stretching even further, multiple parameters.

I can scrape through with this:

```
class ExampleWithNoArgument {
    private val listenerSupport = GenericListenerSupport<Nothing?, (Nothing?)->Unit>()

    fun exampleAdd() {
        listenerSupport.addListener({ System.out.println("I've got no argument")})
    }

    fun exampleFiring() {
        listenerSupport.fireListeners(null)
    }
}
```

but it smells, and obviously it's no use for multiple parameters.

Is there a better way to pull this off? e.g. something supporting this concept:

```
private val listenerSupport = GenericListenerSupport<???, (String, Double)->Unit>()
```

Comment: I would use `Unit` instead of `Nothing?`. As far as multiple parameters go, I don't believe there is a way without using something like `Pair<String, Double>`.

Comment: I did try `Unit` but this produces a compile error relating to `invoke()`. `Nothing?` could be replaced with any nullable type really, including Java's Void (`Void?`), but I like it in one way - it can't be accidentally instantiated.

Comment: Correction: I must have mistakenly tried `Unit()` as `Unit` is of course working OK - the compiler error for the former is unhelpful. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `GenericListenerSupport` declares a type parameter `EventArgumentType` and expects an instance of it in `fun fireListeners(argument: EventArgumentType)`, I doubt you can support multiple arguments in a clean way. Instead, I'd suggest using a data class (which is not so much extra code), as a clean and type-safe way to wrap multiple values:

```
data class MyEvent(val id: String, val value: Double)

private val listenerSupport = GenericListenerSupport<MyEvent, (MyEvent) -> Unit>()
```

As to passing no value, you can also use `Unit`, the type that has exactly one value `Unit`:

```
listenerSupport.fireListeners(Unit)
```

The type system and resolution won't allow you to pass no argument where a single one is expected, but, as [@Ruckus T-Boom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2094298/ruckus-t-boom) suggested, you can make an extension to fire listeners with no value where `Unit` is expected:

```
fun GenericListenerSupport<Unit>.fireListeners() = fireListeners(Unit)
```

---

A bit off-topic, but I think you can simplify the type if you don't need custom function types and `(EventArgumentType) -> Unit` is sufficient:

```
class GenericListenerSupport<EventArgumentType> {
    /* Just use `(EventArgumentType) -> Unit` inside.  */
}
```